# How to use compound drawables in android?

Tags: android, xml

I have this code in my xml file in my android app:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        style="@style/Container" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/avatar"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:background="#00112d"
            android:contentDescription="@string/logoimage"
            android:src="@drawable/no_avatar" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/status"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_profile_status"
            style="@style/RegularBlack"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Android is complaining about turning it into a compound drawable. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Thanks

Comment: Its probably the Lint complaint. You can ignore all the lint issues and proceed (which is not recommended)

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView mStatusTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status)
mStatusTextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,R.id.avatar,0);
```

check this 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29